# Update PFUser from server

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I have one PFUser logged in on two iOS devices. When each app starts, I need to download PFUser data from server to keep latest data (made on the second device).

Is there any method to do that? Because in documentation there is no mention of such thing: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html

Comment: What's a good alternative? I've been having troubles with Parse and would gladly switch.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are two solutions:

1) As Michael mentioned - not to use Parse. :)

2) Or use:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
```